# Can I use Image entropy in noise removal algorithms, in order to check their effectiveness?

Tags: image-processing, noise

I am working in digital image restoration field, I have studied number of image noise removal research papers, and all of these papers are using **PSNR** to check the effectiveness of their algorithms, One thing that I noticed from [SSIM Page](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/research/ssim/), that PSNR, which mainly depends on **MSE** and, **one weakness of MSE is that, this measure depends on scaling of variables despite the fact that the image is invariant to scaling.**.

So Now my question is this.

Can I use Image entropy to check effectiveness of any noise removal method method.

Comment: down voters, or people who think this question is off the topic, kindly dare to put your comments.....

Comment: I think the down voter, does not have DARE to put his/her comments....

Comment: It's a legitimate request. Hell, the API for SO should require a comment for a downvote of a question.

Comment: @Dogbert, at least the questioner will come to know that what is the mistake in either his question, or his way of asking question.

Comment: Not really. They get a negative response, but no indicator of the reason why. I've studied operant vs respondent conditioning (ie: Skinner vs Pavlov). That is a very naive and flippant approach.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can do that, see [ http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=image+denoising+entropy ]

The list shows that entropy is a measure that works better in some domains than others. For example: if you know an optimal basis that efficiently represents your noise-free image (e.g. the Fourier basis or a wavelet basis) but cannot efficiently model noise, your transformed noise-free image will be sparse in the transform domain and your noisey image will not. And sparse signals have a low entropy, while dense signals have a high entropy.

If you know that all these things are true, then you can evaluate your denoising method using a transform-domain entropy measure.

You will need to do some extra work to calibrate your new error message, and of course you cannot use entropy-based methods to do the denoising. That would be double dipping.